# Concurrency and sync among browsers

Tags: multithreading, browser, concurrency, synchronization

I have created an angular application in which data are being shown in a table. An user can update the entry in table cell. What I want is, sync among different browser tabs as well as different browsers for multiple users. As an user updates a value, it should get updated everywhere. Suggest some way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In tabs, you can take a look to [Webstorage](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html) (localStorage is implemented in all modern browsers), but in browsers I think that it's impossible or at least, it has not an inmmediate solution...